# how asp.net update panel conditional update works?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use VS2010,C# to develop a web app for a company, they want to have a music playing while user views their site, I've found some controls (flash and JavaScript) to play mp3 files, but the problem is that whenever there is a postback, music starts to play from beginning, and it is not good, music should continue playing, I've used an update panel with update mode set to conditional, then inserted my JavaScript mp3 player inside this update panel, but when page has a post back (caused by some buttons outside the update panel) my music starts from beginning! I think setting update mode to conditional should update the update panel only when there is a postback caused by controls inside it, how can I prevent my JavaScript player from re-start when there is an outside postback? should I use something else? what is going wrong here?

```
                    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="http://www.phenomenontest.com/audio-player.js"></script>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.phenomenontest.com/player.swf" id="audioplayer1" height="24" width="290">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.phenomenontest.com/player.swf"/>
<param name="FlashVars" value="autostart=yes&playerID=audioplayer1&soundFile=http://www.phenomenontest.com/silas.mp3"/>
<param name="quality" value="high"/>
<param name="menu" value="false"/>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
</object> 
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put button which caused postback inside update panel and set the UpdateMode to "Always".

Comment: it made no change, I'm going to implement a scenario in which my music continues playing, regardless of postbacks, opening new pages or anything else, I could do it using frames but frames destroy my layout, perhaps I need master page? and perhaps Ajax should be mixed with it, how is it possible?

Comment: Instead of updatepanel, you can use button click with client side code and call the server method through "WebMethod", this will stop the postback.

Comment: so you mean I should stop postback? is it possible to navigate to other pages, set sessions and perform normal tasks without postbacking? is it possible to use DB?

Comment: You can perform tasks only on one page not for navigation, but in order to do this, you have to write javascript for accessing or setting controls, rest should be done on server method tagged as WebMethod.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Put this code in 1 page audio.aspx**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>   
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="http://www.phenomenontest.com/audio-player.js"></script>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.phenomenontest.com/player.swf" id="audioplayer1" height="24" width="290"> 
<param name="movie" value="http://www.phenomenontest.com/player.swf"/> 
<param name="FlashVars" value="autostart=yes&playerID=audioplayer1&soundFile=http://www.phenomenontest.com/silas.mp3"/> 
<param name="quality" value="high"/> 
<param name="menu" value="false"/> 
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/> 
</object>
```

**Put this code in Head of Main.aspx**

```
<frameset rows="1%,99%">
<frame src="Audio.aspx" />
<frame src="Page1.aspx" />
</frameset>
```

Comment: it will stop postbacking? but I have buttons or menus on the page that will navigate user to other pages or set some sessions, how can I handle it?

Comment: Hi Ali please don't forget to vote if my answer was helpful and accept it as answer if you think it is,Thank you.